# removing duplicates from a mySQL table using a two-column combination?s

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I have a table that looks like this:

```
Tx1   TX2   Val
SP1   SP1   1
SP1   SP2   0.56
SP1   SP3   0.78
SP2   SP1   0.56
SP2   SP2   1
SP2   SP3   0.47
SP3   SP1   0.78
SP3   SP2   0.47
SP3   SP3   1
```

I'd like mySQL to sort the duplicates out using all combinations of cols 1 and 2 (Tx1&2). Such that I get:

```
Tx1   TX2   Val
SP1   SP1   1
SP1   SP2   0.56
SP1   SP3   0.78
SP2   SP2   1
SP2   SP3   0.47
SP3   SP3   1
```

Can anyone suggest a query that will do this?

Thanks,
Dave.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of the table? What is the rule for detecting duplicates? Does the value need to be the same as well? If not which value should be kept for a particular `Tx1&2` combination?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM tablename
  GROUP BY CONCAT(Tx1,":",Tx2)
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

I believe this only deletes the first duplicate. So if you have triplicates (etc.), you'll have to run the query again.

Comment: Thanks Paul, does that take into account the issue where you have SP2 & SP3 vs SP3 & SP2? If they are concatenated wont those two things look different?

Comment: No, it won't handle that case. I can't think of anything clever at the moment. It would be much easier to do this in code (PHP, etc.).